# Clickhouse kafka engine - how to move messages with parsing error to a different queue

Tags: clickhouse

I'm pushing analytics data to a table using materialized view from a queue table that uses kafka engine. I use JSONEachRow as kafka format and it is possible to get occasional json parsing error. How can I move the failed messages to a dead letter queue to inspect and skip it from processing?

Comment: Unfortunately at this moment, this feature not implemented but probably soon it appears - [How kafka_skip_broken_messages should works #10647](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/10647#issuecomment-623404036)

Comment: Look at [Altinity Kafka FAQ: Q. How can I deal with malformed messages?](https://altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-kafka-engine-faq) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting for skipping broken messages called this `kafka_skip_broken_messages`.

Unfortunately, as pointed by an [Altinity Blog post](https://altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-kafka-engine-faq) it does not work as expected for now.

> Another setting is ‘kafka_skip_broken_messages.’ It does not work for all formats, and sometimes can produce unexpected results.

My solution was to use Kafka Stream and a [JSON Schema Validator](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema) to validate each message first, then send the validated message to another topic that ClickHouse read from.